# Mkmapview how to set directions for multiple places?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have this app with many screens on it and I have 9 different screens wich each of them I have the map button so I imported the map kit framework and core location framework then I created a view controller with mkmapview on it then linked all 9 screens to it and when I simulated it actually work but what I need to do now is that I want to set 9 different locations but I have no clue on how to do that. Do I have to create multiple mapview for each screen? Or do I have to use webview instead?

Comment: I used mainly the storyboard and it is for iOS 6

Comment: If the question is for iOS, why is there an _android_-mapview tag?  Suggest you tag it with: iOS, mapkit, storyboard.  Do you mean 9 screens will all call some common view controller that has a map view on it and each of the 9 screens will show a different location?  Including some code like the map view controller's .h file might help the question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do but how?